# maximise $\sin^2(x) +\sinh^2(y)$ subject to $x^2+y^2=1$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I want to maximise $\sin^2(x) +\sinh^2(y)$ subject to $x^2+y^2 =1$

I tried to use Lagrange multipliers but got nowhere. Then, I tried to parametrise $x=cos(t)$, $y=sin(t)$.

I obtained  $$\cos(t) (-\sin(2\cos(t)) +\sinh(2\sin(t))) =0 $$ 
The solutions I am after are there, namely $\cos (t) =0$ gives $t= 2 \pi n \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$. However, I can't figure out how to deal with the other bracket. I want to differentiate again and show that those solutions give minimum, but I am stuck. I feel like there is an easier way.

Comment: Looks to be that the solutions are $\{ (0,1), (0,-1)\} $.

Comment: @mjw Don't you mean $\{(0,\,1),\,(0,\,-1)\}$ (since $\sinh^21>\sin^21$)?

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I made a plot and interpreted it the opposite of what we are looking for.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: we want to prove minimizing $|\sin\color{blue}{z}|$ subject to $|z|=1$ gives $z=\pm i$.

Answer (score 2):

Lagrange multipliers still works. We get the following system of equations

$$\begin{cases}\sin(2x) = \lambda (2x)\\ \sinh(2y) = \lambda (2y)\\ x^2+y^2=1\end{cases}$$

Now geometrically consider the intersection of $\lambda z$ with $\sin(z)$ and $\sinh(z)$. Changing lambda changes the slope and notice that for $\lambda > 1$, the first equation will only ever have one intersection (at $z=0$), but the other equation will have three intersections, at $z=\pm$ some arbitrary value specified by the choice of $\lambda$, and $z=0$.

But recognize that the last equation says that if one value is fixed to $0$, the other must be $\pm 1$, so finding $\lambda$ is no longer necessary since we have shown that it is possible to choose a $\lambda$ to allow $z=2\cdot(\pm 1)$ to be a solution.

A similar thing happens with $\lambda < 1$, but with the roles of the equations reversed. So we get the following points to check from Lagrange multipliers:

$$(0,\pm 1)\hspace{16pt}(\pm 1, 0) \implies f(\pm 1, 0) = \sin^2(1)\hspace{16 pt} f(0,\pm 1) = \sinh^2(1)$$

and we can conclude that the function is minimized at $(\pm 1, 0)$ and maximized at $(0,\pm 1)$

Answer (score 1):

The parametrized function is

$$f(t) = \sin^2(\cos t) +\sinh^2(\sin t)$$

Set $f'(t) = 0$ for the extrema,

$$-\sin(2\cos t)\sin t + \sinh(2\sin t)\cos t=0$$

which has solutions at $t = \pm \frac\pi2,0,\pi$. Given that $f(t)$ is bounded, it is straightforward to verify that the maximum value is at

$$f(\pm\frac\pi2) = \sinh^2(1)$$

while the minimum is at $f(0)=f(\pi)=\sin^2(1)$.

Comment: How do we know there might not be more solutions that are larger than $\sinh^2 (1)$?

Comment: @SeanThrasher - Note that $f(t)$ is continuous, bounded and differentiable, with extrema at $0, \pm\frac\pi2, \pi$. Then, you may verify the maximum at $f(\pm\frac\pi2) = \sinh^21$ and minimum at $f(0)=f(\pi) = \sin^2(1)$.

Comment: Did you prove that $f'(t) = 0$ has no other solutions than $t = \pm \frac\pi2,0,\pi$?

Answer (score 1):

For $x, y \in \Bbb R$ we have
$$ 
\sin^2(x) + \sinh^2(y) = |\sin(x+iy)|^2 \, ,
$$
see for example [How to show $|\sin(x+iy)|^2=\sin^2x+\sinh^2y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149872/how-to-show-sinxiy2-sin2x-sinh2y).

From the power series expansion we get for all $z \in \Bbb C$
$$ 
|\sin(z)| = \left| \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right|
\le  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ |z|^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} = \sinh(|z|)
$$
with equality for purely imaginary $z$.

It follows that for $x^2+y^2=1$
$$
\sin^2(x) + \sinh^2(y) = |\sin(x+iy)|^2 \le \sinh^2 (|x+iy|) = \sinh^2(1) \, ,
$$
with equality for $(x, y) = (0, \pm 1)$.